# How to run an Azure Pipeline DotNetCoreCLI task on Linux with permissions?

Tags: azure-pipelines, sudo, azure-pipelines-tasks, dotnetcorecli

I have the following azure pipeline task snippet below, running on Linux self hosted agents.

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run Dotnet Test
      inputs:
        command: test
        #arguments: --blame-hang-timeout 2min (supported only in .net 5 and above)
        projects: 'Test/UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj'
        verbosityPack: detailed
```

**What is the way to run this with sudo permissions** ? Part of my tests require the execution of some external processes with sudo permissions (like dmidecode, etc).

The only way I can think of is giving up using the DotNetCoreCLI task and using a regular CmdLine or other bash script task instead (actually this is the approach I was using before, I just happened to solve an issue of not having log output being printed to the console output in a Windows host - by switching from running a `dotnet test` within a script block to a DotNetCoreCLI task - and thought this would be preferable as well in my linux self hosted agents).

The user that runs the pipeline job is already configured under /etc/sudoers (this was required in order to succeed running `sudo dotnet test` as I originally did, as mentioned above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the obvious answer is yes, run a [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task and manually run your dotnet commands there, including dotnet test - and - prefixing them with sudo. As stated above, this is what I have been doing, I just thought that it would be better to use the [DotNetCoreCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task.

But the main reason I wanted to use [DotNetCoreCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops), is that it automatically publishes the test results and attaches it to the job run.

I ultimately found a workaround for that:

1. Run your dotnet commands via [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task, prefixed with sudo, as desired
2. Add a new task - [Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml), right after.

The same test results job attachment behavior is achieved.